# File Manager access in iphone for custom application

Tags: iphone

How can i get to File manager access in iphone for my application which have downloads option

Thank you.

Comment: Ask a more specific question, what are you trying to do? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

you can get downloads directory by passing argument NSDownloadsDirectory to the method NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.
like this

```
NSArray *directoryArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *downloadsDir = [directoryArray objectAtIndex:0];
```